# Get path to java JRE

Tags: java

It it possible to get the location of the jre that is used for the current process. Need to launch an other java application as a separate process. Having different jre's available (and no path variable set) I would like ask eg. the loader for this. Running on Solaris, Linux, Windows.

Answer (score 47):

You can use:

```
System.getProperty("java.home")
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29 says:

> java.home:    Java installation directory

Comment: .. and what if another JRE was used to start the currently running JVM (which I believe is possible, correct me if I'm wrong), i.e., no the one installed in JAVA_HOME?

Comment: It returns the path to the JRE that is used to run the program which does the lookup. It is not related to JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 10):

```
System.getProperty("java.home")
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));`

The code above will return the full physical path to current jvm's jre path. Tested only in Windows 10.