# Get path to java.exe

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, path

I need help with getting path to java.exe. But I need it to do with java code. And I want it to work on Linux and Mac and on other systems too, so there won't be java.exe, I don't know what's there.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do that? [What is your real problem?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Are you trying to run a `.jar` or `.class`? Because there are **much** better ways of doing that.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this post. [Get path to the JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531626/get-path-to-java-jre)

It explains how to get the path of where your java.exe bin/java file lies on your OS.

Also see the docs for more properties that are available

[Java System.getProperty docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)